# How can I upload my code to Atmega328p?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, atmega328p, prototyping

There is no problem with uploading program on the first chip by using Arduino IDE.

[image: first one]

However, the following chips doesn’t work. Status is shown as uploading and it hangs there. I think it could be because datasheet says 20Mhz for these. if so, how can I use them? Why doesn't it work?

Thank you for help.

[image]

I have posted my question here and also on the arduino forum.

Comment: Is the bootloader programmed into them?

Comment: Which programmer did you used?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am using standard controller board. Should the bootloader be programmed?

Comment: @Mike AVRISPmkll

Comment: With Atmel/Microchip Studio?

Comment: @Mike He/she said that they used the Arduino IDE

Comment: yes, i use Arduino IDE

Answer (score 3):

The arduino IDE works because the is a "bootloader" programmed into the 328P's that Arduino uses.

This bootloader allows the chip to be programmed using RX/TX TTL pins instead of the regular programmer.

You can actually use one Arduino to program the bootloader into another. One (of many) tutorials is [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoToBreadboard):

Comment: thanks. then problem is probably that no bootloader progammed in. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arcatus said, the bootloader allows the chip to be programmed with the RX/TX pins using a USB-serial converter.

You can upload your code to the 328P by selecting the programmer you use and holding the shift key down while clicking the upload button.

This will overwrite the boot-loader but as long as you only upload using the programmer, the bootloader isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a program to an atmega without a bootloader you first need to compile the code (e.g. using `avr-gcc`). Once you have a .hex-file of your firmware, use [`avrdude`](https://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html) to upload it via [ISP](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/atmel-0943-in-system-programming_applicationnote_avr910.pdf)

Comment: You can upload the compiled code using programmer in the Arduino IDE. The IDE will do the Avrdude bit for you.